# Open source firmware for Internet modem ZTE ZXV10 W300

Tags: open-source, firmware

I've been playing around with my own router and found DD-WRT as an open source firmware alternative for this kind of device but I can't find something equivalent for modems.

Can you recommend something?

My modem is a ZTE ZXV10 W300.

Comment: What modem do you want to put the firmware on. Also do you have any settings or features you want with the firmware.

Comment: Te modem is a ZTE ZXV10 W300. Don't want any particular feature.